# C++ Time machine doesn't calculate amount of time passed correctly

Tags: c++

In the textbook Problem Solving with C++ there is a problem that says you have a time machine that can travel 24 hours forward in time, it wants you to input the start time and end time using a hour value, a minute value, and a boolean value that represents whether or not the time is AM or PM and figure out how many minutes have passed. I wanted to do this with military time instead, I am able to figure out how many minutes if the start time is less than the end time (ie. the times 0000 and 2359 return 1439) but I can't figure out how to do the reverse.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int timeDifference(int t1, int t2)
{
    int t1_mins = (t1 / 100) * 60 + (t1 % 100);
    int t2_mins = (t2 / 100) * 60 + (t2 % 100);
    return(t2_mins - t1_mins);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "The time difference between 0000 and 2359 is " <<
        timeDifference(0,2359) << " minutes." << endl;
    cout << "The time difference between 2359 and 0001 is " <<
        timeDifference(2359,1) << " minutes." << endl;
    cout << "The time difference between 2010 and 1000 is " <<
        timeDifference(2010,1000) << " minutes." << endl;
    cout << "The time difference between 0300 and 1500 is " <<
        timeDifference(300,1500) << " minutes." << endl;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Well what do you want it to output for `timeDifference(2359,1)`? 2?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes, and for timeDifference(2010, 1000) it should be 830.

Comment: `std::chrono::duration` and `time_point` might make this a big cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If t2 is smaller than t1, just add the minutes of one full day to t2.

This would result in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int timeDifference(int t1, int t2)
{
    int t1_mins = (t1 / 100) * 60 + (t1 % 100);
    int t2_mins = (t2 / 100) * 60 + (t2 % 100);
    if ( t2 < t1 )
        t2_mins += 24 * 60;
    return(t2_mins - t1_mins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::chrono` makes things nicer...

Given 24hour time input durations:

```
using namespace std::chrono;

minutes timeDifference(minutes t1, minutes t2)
{
    if(t2 < t1)
        t2 += 24h;

    return t2 - t1;
}
```